# Unable to locate webelement on text box?

Tags: selenium

I used below link to automate testing:
**https://roundtheworld.skyteam.com/B2C/en/Home/WelcomePage**

but I am not able to locate the text box web element.

please let me know, if any body know the solution how to locate web element for this website.

Comment: Which element you need to identify? From or passengers?

Comment: I need to identify From text box... but if i tried for Inspect by right click it disabled and not able to see the locators.

Comment: This XPATH has to work -> //div/input[@name='CityOfOrigin']

Answer (score 0):

You can access the text box web element marked with placeholder `From` through any of the following `xpath`:

```
//input[@id='CityOfOrigin']
```

> or

```
//input[@name='CityOfOrigin']
```

> or

```
//input[@title='From']
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 0):

May this can help you :- `//div[@class="inner_circle"]/form//*/input[contains(@name,"CityOfOrigin")]` .If you want to locate some other field u just need to find attribute and put it in side xpath

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome , either use F12 or ctrl+shift+i to open developer console and than you can do the inspection of element using find function. Hope this helps your problem in inspecting the element. For Firefox use Shift+f2 & for Edge use F12 to open developer option.

There are id and name present for the textbox so you can use them inplace of xpath or css

```
driver.find_element_by_id('CityOfOrigin').send_keys("This is test")

driver.find_element_by_name('CityOfOrigin').send_keys("This is test1")
```